# what size should I choose to show fullscreen images in different 1x,2x,3x iPads

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I am working on designing a universal (iPhone, iPad) application, this app is portrait only,  and I want the application show some fullscreen  images to users.
I edited my images size for (iPhone) like this in `1x=> 320*480px` and `2x=> 750*1334px` and for `3x=>1125*2436px`.

now I am designing the app for different iPads. I searched a lot to find whats the best sizes for 1x and 2x and maybe 3x `iPads` but I couldn't find any exact pixels which I should choose for my images. its very important for me to show images with high quality and no and no stretch. 
my question is what sizes in pixel should I choose for my images to shown in iPads perfectly.(full screen and portrait).

Appreciate any help.

Comment: If you have a 1x image at 320x480, the 2x would be 640x960, not 750x1334. And the 3x would be 960x1440, not 1125x2436. But none of that has anything to do with the size of an iPad screen.

Comment: in pixels? @rmaddy

Comment: Yes, in pixels.

Comment: thank you very much @rmaddy I followed link below to reach that sizes, you mean it all is wrong? https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

Comment: No, you are talking about two completely different things.

Comment: @rmaddy thank you very much. I will continue with this new knowledge. if you like and answer me I will accept . thank you again